# I need to get the path instead of selecting file name in my browse dialog box to save my file

Tags: java, html, security, file-upload, forms

This is my code. This will take only the filename. I want my browse dialog to select the path location to save my file.

```
<form name="uploadFile" method="POST"  
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="myfile"><br />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Save file or upload file?

Comment: 1) *"i need to get the path instead of"*  You can't, it would be a security risk.  End of story.  2) Note that JSP becomes HTML by the time the browser sees it, so HTML is the more useful tag.

Comment: thank you. I need to save my file. For my application I need a save as dialog box to save my file in specific location.

Comment: @Thihara I'm trying to save my file in dynamic location

Comment: @Vigesh you cannot pick where your file is to be saved in a browser except via malicious methods..

Comment: Or Java applet or active x control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. The server cannot know where the user is saving his file.
And even if you get the path, then what? You cannot access the client's machine.
You need not worry about the path. Just give the user a file to download, and the browser will open a dialog asking him/her for the path.